# import is successful in jupyter notebook but fails with cmd

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed torch using pip, and it went successfully! When I import it in jupyter notebook it is successfull. But when I try to use it cmd, it fails! any help?

Below is what shows on my cmd

```
C:\Users\my_pc_name>python
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Comment: check about any other version you are using? or virtual environment?

Comment: Show us the command with which you start the notebook server, I guess that'll solve the issue

Comment: Hello  LcdDrm, I start the notebook in all programs from the start button.

Comment: Hello, Subbu VidyaSekar, I have found that I have 2 versions of python. In conda, it is 3.8.5, in python  for windows cmd it is 3.8.10. Kindly advise how I can make 3.8.5 the default version. Thank you.